# Show the sequence of partial sums is cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, cauchy-sequences

Let $A\in L(\mathbb R^n)$, and set $C_j=\sum\limits_{i=0}^j \frac {A^i}{i!}$.

I'm trying to show that $C_j$ is a Cauchy sequence wrt the operator norm.

So far I have $||C_m-C_n||=||\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m\frac{A^i}{i!}||\leq\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m\frac{||A||^i}{i!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In finite dimensional spaces evey linear operator is bounded.

So $||A|| \leq M$ for some $M>0$

The series $\sum_{i=n+1}^m\frac{M^i}{i!} \to^{m,n \to +\infty} 0$ by convergence of the series,for every $M>0$

So the sequence $C_j$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using that the linear operator is bounded?

Comment: I believe that even if someone tries,he will end up using the boundness of the operator..Im not absolutely sure though..lets wait..if someone post an answer that fits you better and is more helpfull to you, i will delete mine

Comment: What you mean rigorously? the series converges and the partial sums are Cauchy,so it will exist $N$ such that e.t.c it is the same..it is rigorous